# how to highlight errors (false fields) in power query?

Tags: highlight, powerquery

Here is the task:
Automatically check the quality of data in specific columns as per rules described in the table below. If possible, use color coding to emphasize False fields but if not possible, other options are acceptable. The main idea is to make errors in data visible.

Any ideas how to color code these false fields or other option of making errors visible in Power query? Checking the quality of data with IF functions, and the False part should be visualised.

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You can't adjust color in the query editor. Errors might stand out more than False though.

Here's an example of what Errors compared to nulls looks like:

[image]